# Not able to run code after the Main.main() method in cucumber

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Is there any way i can run some code after the `Main.main()` method?

```
System.out.println("execution start");
Main.main(new String[]{"-g","","./src/main/java/featureDetails/Testing.feature"});
System.out.println("execution over");
```

In this case system not able to print `execution over`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) of `Main.main()` you'll notice that it contains: `System.exit(exitstatus)` which terminates the system before it can return control to your method and print the message.

The proper way to run the commandline programatically would be to use:

```
String [] argv = new String[]{ "-g","","./src/main/java/featureDetails/Testing.feature"};
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
byte exitstatus = Main.run(argv, contextClassLoader);
```